# How to unserialize an object in initializeAction before it gets mapped

Tags: php, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

got a big problem which is difficult to describe.

Got an indexAction which has a parameter like this:

```
public funcion indexAction(SearchParameter $searchParameter){
...
$this->view->assign('searchParameter', $searchParameter);
$this->view->assign('searchParameterSer', serialize($searchParameter));
}
```

$searchParameter is a model in classes/domain/model ...

In my view I got a url.action view helper using the "searchParameterSer" like this

```
controller... 
action... resultset
arguments: {searchParameterSer: searchParameterSer}
```

In the controller I try to allocate searchParameter
public function searchAction(SearchParameter $searchParameter){
...
}

But it does not work. So I tried to map it...

```
public function initializeSearchAction(){
 $this->arguments->get('searchParameterSer')-> ????
}
```

how can I solve that $searchParameter is of type SearchParameter with the values from serialized parameters.

Any hint for me?

regards
n00n

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with an ObjectConverter....